# Javascript array with values

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements, output

The below code is a javascript interview question. I should get the output as [5,1,2,3,4]. Anyone can help me out this.

```
const input = [1,2,3,4,5]
const n = 4;



var output = []

console.log(output)
```

Comment: What is the logic behind the output result? What are you supposed to do with `n` and `input` to get the result?

Comment: `output = [5,1,2,3,4]` - there you go. For anything more dynamic, we need to know *what* the actual requirement is and also where are you stuck when implementing it.

Comment: We have to find the logic to bring the output as 5,1,2,3,4 of using variable 4

Comment: Easy! `if (n === 4) return [5,1,2,3,4];` But I fear this is a terrible interview question, since I can give that answer to it. There is at least two other alternatives - rotating the array `n` times or moving the last item by `n` indexes. They are all valid and it's all pointing to a garbage question.

Comment: Strange interview question, maybe they want you to shift the array backwards `n` times: `[1,2,3,4,5] -> [2,3,4,5,1] -> [3,4,5,1,2] -> [4,5,1,2,3] -> [5,1,2,3,4]`, but they should at least give you more inputs/outputs

Comment: @VLAZ Can you write the program. It would be easy for me to understand.

Comment: @Mohamedfaruk [take your pick](https://jsbin.com/biwopuxune/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without modifying the input array:

```js
const input = [1,2,3,4,5]
const n = 4;

var output = []

output= [input[n],input.slice(0,n)].flat()

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, the question is that when 'n' is a given index, you should be able to remove the element from the index n of the array and insert it at the very beginning of the array. As arrays are 0 based, it means that if n=4, then the element at nth index is 5 as per the given array.

In order to do that, you can do the following:

1. Use the splice method on the nth index and pass 1 as 2nd parameter, so you only remove the element at nth index.
2. Then use the unshift method on input to remove add the nth element at the beginning of the array. Unshift returns the length of the array, but you want the entire array to be stored in output.
3. So, you store the input array in the output variable.

Please run the below snippet for a better understanding. Let me know if my understanding of your question is not correct, so I can update my answer accordingly.

```js
const input = [1,2,3,4,5]
const n = 4;

const [el] = input.splice(n,1); //array destructuring
input.unshift(el);
const output = input;

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Why isn't it "move the last element `n` positions back"?

Comment: It can be that too. But move the last element n positions back means move all the other elements forward as well, which is why I didn't think of that as the obvious choice for an interview question. However, If the interviewer was looking to see if OP knew his way around working with arrays and Array prototype functions, my solution's question would be a good question.  IMO.

Comment: I disagree. The interview question is terrible and whoever asked it should be ashamed. The question here is also bad by extension because *we have no idea what it's asking of us*. It's unclear and unanswerable. How is a future visitor even going to benefit from it? They google "how to do something with array", somehow land here, and somehow they manage to find whatever they needed to do?

Comment: The question is unclear, has no guidance, no way of deriving a correct answer or a measure for what a correct answer *is*. It's a terrible question to ask at an interview where you want to be as clear as possible and not put too much strain on the candidates who are already under a lot of stress. Interviewers use such questions can make a candidate slip up which *should be* the exactly the opposite of what an interview is about. This makes them a bad interviewer. It's much worse if it's actually intentional as part of those "stress interviews".

Comment: The "interview question" the one OP has posted. The "whoever asked it" is the person who conducted interview with OP and gave that question (at least I assume OP saw this at an interview).

Comment: Thanks to all. 
But interview person gave me four answers 
a) [2,3,4,5,1]  
b) [3,4,5,1,2]  
c) [4,5,1,2,3]  
d) [5,1,2,3,4]
Whenever he change the variable n to 1,2,3,etc.. above answer has to come.

Comment: @Mohamedfaruk next time you should probably include that information in the original question. The more details the better

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [1,2,3,4,5]
const n = 4

input.splice(0, 0, input[n])
input.splice(n+1, 1)

var output = [...input]
console.log(output)
```

Comment: You're not using `n`.